# Understanding analog pins in pinMode

Tags: pins

When passing the pin number in pinMode its possible to use A0 - A7, does it apply only to that methode? 
How can pinMode expect a number (is it int?) type in case of digital pin another (is it then string?) in case of analog pin?
I want to use that in my class methode, is there a way to use that and have my code more readable or should I use the pin numbers?
P.S. I have tried to read the source code but I don't understand the uin8_t (I know its a byte, but not how it can understand A5 as an int)

Tnx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pinMode is actually declared as `void pinMode(uint8_t, uint8_t);`  in arduino.h

A0 is a defined as a number (somewhere depending on the actual hardware), on an Uno/Nano it translates to 14, and when executing pinMode it translates to the appopriate bit in the correct DDRx register.

Comment: On an atmega328 Arduino pin 14 ( or A0 ) is directed to PORTA bit 0, which can be used as a digital I/O or alternatively as an ADC channel.

Comment: The ATmega328 doesn't have a port 0. pin 14 (A0) is PC0.

Comment: Correct: PORTC Bit 0  Thanks.   In the DIP28 atmega328P-PU its Pin 23